# How can i get a popup window for my results?

Tags: output, popup

I dont know how to get the results into a popup window i tried a lot of things but nothing works. Can anyone help me? I want the erge and erge 1 to be in the new window. Here is my current code:

```
{n, p} = Input["Eingabe der Parameter in der Form {n,p}
   n=Größe der Stichprobe
   p=Wahrscheinlichkeit"];
Stichp4 = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], n];
xquer = N[1/n \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
       1\), \(n\)]\(Stichp4[\([i]\)]\)\)];
pneu = xquer;
erge = Print["Geschätzter Parameter p = ", xquer]
erge1 = Print["Abweichung zum wahren Parameter p: ", Abs[pneu - p]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See `PopupView`

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange in the form of a button "Click to print" using `PopupWindow[]`:

```
{n, p} = Input["Eingabe der Parameter in der Form {n,p}
      n=Größe der Stichprobe
      p=Wahrscheinlichkeit"];
Stichp4 = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], n];
xquer = N[1/n \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
       1\), \(n\)]\(Stichp4[\([i]\)]\)\)];
pneu = xquer;
PopupWindow[
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[], Inset["Click to print", {0, 0}]}], 
 Grid[{{"Geschätzter Parameter p = ", 
    xquer}, {"Abweichung zum wahren Parameter p: ", Abs[pneu - p]}}]]
```

[image: fig1]